# making a special character (@) mandatory in php preg_match()

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to create a preg_match() for Bcc in the mail().
I have created below preg_match()

```
if(empty($mail_bcc))
        {
            $_SESSION['error'] .= "<li>Please enter BCC email id.</li>";
            $error = 1;
        }
         else if(!preg_match('/^\s*[A-Za-z0-9@. ,]+\s*$/',$mail_bcc)|| preg_match('/^ /',$mail_bcc) || preg_match('/ $/',$mail_bcc))
        {
            $_SESSION['error'] .= "<li>Please enter a valid BCC email id.No spaces are allowed and Separate BCC email addresses with commas (,)</li>";
            $error = 1;
        }
```

for this i'm getting below result

1. abc.gmail.com = TRUE
2. abc.gmail.com,abc.gmail.com = TRUE
3. abc@gmail.com = = TRUE

but I want to make @ mandatory.
for below cases it should return False/Error

1. abc.gmail.com = FALSE
2. abc.gmail.com,abc.gmail.com FALSE

Comment: Try `'/^(?=[^@]*@)\s*[A-Za-z0-9@. ,]+\s*$/'`.

Comment: @JasshhAndrews do you want to validate email address or doing anything else?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: it worked.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: can you just help me. which is the best site for beginners to learn Regex. I just hate them. my regex never gives me the correct result.

Comment: There are a lot. Still, to really learn something you need to practice. The best way to practice is through real problem solving. Basics can be learned at http://regexone.com, the rest can be mastered here, on SO. Subscribe to regex tag, or just search the site with `[regex] [php]` tags in the search box. Use http://regex101.com to test PCRE compatible expressions (the site also provides great explanation of the pattern automatically). PHP.net is also a great resource.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot. It was really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To require at least one `@` in a regex like yours, the simplest approach is to use a `(?=[^@]*@)` positive lookahead:

```
'/^(?=[^@]*@)\s*[A-Za-z0-9@. ,]+\s*$/'
   ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?=[^@]*@)` construct will start looking for any 0+ chars other than `@` (`[^@]*`) up to the first `@` right from the start of the string (`^`). If it finds a `@`, the rest of the consuming pattern will be searched for, else, the regex engine will fail the match right away.